# Can a SCD 2 table have non SCD columns?

Tags: database, etl, data-warehouse, scd, scd2

Lets say there is a table schema where in the columns are a,b,c,d,start_time,end_time,current_status.

Can we have a,b,c as SCD columns and let d not be a part of SCD logic so that if d changes, it wont create a new SCD row?

Comment: You can do whatever you want that meets your business requirements

Answer (score 1):

The Type 2 SCD is called Row Versioning where you cab track changes as version records with current flag & active dates and other metadata.
Do not forget that after you have implemented your chosen dimension type, you need to point your fact records at the relevant business or surrogate key. Surrogate keys in the SCD type 2 relate to a specific historical version of the record, removing join complexity from later data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if d column value changes, the record is overwritten.